# How to add data from JSON to HTML with jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to add data from a JSON object to HTML markup. I use jQuery and AJAX to read out the data. What I want to achieve is that there will be add for each object in the JSON file a new HTML markup that represent an item.

I use the following code to add the `text` key from each object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/videoData.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); //uncomment this for debug

        for (var i = 0; i < data.content.length; i++) {
            if (data.content[i].type == 'normal') {
                console.log(data.content[i].text);
                $('.article.text').find('p').html(data.content[i].text);
            }
        };
    },
    error: function() { 
        console.log('Houston, we have a problem!');
    }
});
```

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="article text">
    <span class="format text alignRight"></span>

    <h4>Subtitle</h4>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>
        Paragraph text
    </p>
</div><!-- End div.article text -->
```

JSON FILE:

```
{
    "title":    "London",
    "category": "The Ultimate",
    "image":    "images/content/londen.jpg",
    "website":  "http://www.london.nl/",
    "youtube":  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq9rjbouBlY&t=23",
    "maps":     "https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Londen,+Verenigd+Koninkrijk/@51.5114089,-0.1271477,13.79z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99",
    "content":  [
        {
            "type" :        "normal",
            "timeTrigger":  24,
            "title":        "London Eye",
            "subtitle":     "Algemene",
            "picture" :     "images/content/london.jpg",
            "text":         "This is the London Eye",
            "readmore":     "http://wikitravel.org/en/London"
        },{
            "type":         "normal",
            "timeTrigger":  24,
            "title":        "Sherlock Holmes",
            "subtitle":     "Detective",
            "picture" :     "images/content/sherlock_holmes.jpg",
            "text":         "Sherlock Holmes is een fictieve detective  <br> uit de verhalen van de laat-19de-eeuwse",
            "readmore":     "http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes"
        },{
            "type":         "normal",
            "timeTrigger":  39,
            "title":        "Fish \"n Chips",
            "subtitle":     "Eten",
            "picture" :     "images/content/sherlock_holmes.jpg",
            "text":         "Fish and chips is een typisch Britse afhaalmaaltijd .",
            "readmore":     "http://youngandfoodish.com/london/top-10-fish-and-chips-in-london/"
        }
    ]
}
```

It will `console.log` all the text of all my objects, but it doesn't appear in my HTML.

Comment: Your `$('.article.text').find('p')` selector keeps changing the content of the same element(s), what do you expect?

Comment: If you showed the structure of your HTML and the receive data we wouldn't have to guess how it looks like.

Comment: can you show what you are getting as `response`?

Comment: Yeah please show a portion of your HTML & JSON.

Comment: Use jquery append() in your loop instead of html()

Comment: I have update my post with more code, like my JSON and basic markup that the code should create for each object in my JSON file.

Comment: you can use a templating system for rendering JSON data in html, have a look on this : https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `append` instead of `html` because:

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was
>   in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

from the jquery API: [API .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

You can also use jquery `each` instead of the for loop:
[API $.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Use a markup like these where your articles will be appended:

```
<div id="articles"></div>
```

...your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'api/videoData.js',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); //uncomment this for debug
            Triptube.dataController.timelineEvents(data);

            //the element where the articles should be appended
            var el = $('#articles');

            //empty this element first
            el.empty();

            //you can use jquery each to append all new articles
            $.each(data.content, function(index, value) {
                if (value.type == 'normal') {
                    console.log(value.text);

                    //append every node instead of replacing it with your markup
                    el.append(
                       '<div class="article text">' +
                          '<span class="format text alignRight"></span>' +
                          '<h4>' + value.subtitle + '</h4>' + 
                          '<h3>' + value.title + '</h3>' +
                          '<p>' + value.text + '</p>' +
                       '</div>'
                    );

                }
            });
        },
        error: function() { // Moet deze ook een parameter hebben?
            console.log('Houston, we have a problem!');
        }
});
```

APIs:

[API .empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

[API .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I may ask you one more question, how can I do this the best way for also the hole item. SO not only de paragraph, but for each object the code should create or duplicate the basic markup and fill it in with content from my JSON.

Comment: Just build your markup as string and let jquery append it as html to your element. So i would do for example: `el.append('<div><h3>' + value.title + '</h3><span>' + value.text + '</span></div>')`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with your markup! I named your parent element, where you append your articles markup `#articles` but that is your choice.

Comment: Thank you. I checked it already. One question, index is not used in the function parameter? What does index exactly? Is this needed or?

Comment: It is only a possible parameter which is the index of your element in the list (like an array index and you could use it to do something special with the third element for example). There is no need to use it, but it should appear in the declaration of the function. You could alternatively use `$.each(function() {});` without any parameters and access your value with `$(this)`.

Comment: So with the index I can, for example say show the first three objects and if a button is clicked load more content?

Comment: No it just say which element index you handle now. It is like the `i` variable in your for loop. `values` is similar to the statement `data.content[index]`. If you want to see the value of index, just use it in your markup (for example `...'<h3>Index: ' + index + ' - ' + value.title + '</h3>'...`

Comment: Of course. I got it. It's just the same as i in my previous for loop... Thanks for the reminder!